# Identify these components for bluetooth speaker

Tags: batteries, bluetooth, speakers, diy

I am wanting to make my own DIY bluetooth speaker (first time electronics project) and I have found several good Youtube videos on the topic. However when it comes to finding the actual parts, I am struggling.

Many videos give different parts and I'm unsure of which would go together and if they are even compatible.

I like the design of [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtdtcyrtbFw) speaker in particular since there are few components that go into the build, however I cannot identify them and the Youtuber does not list their parts, just a link to their own page to sell the kit that is no longer functional.

I wondered if anybody could identify the specific part names/numbers?

I understand that they are as follows:

- Bluetooth & amplifier chip
- 18650 Li-Ion battery
- Protection circuit (*I have seen micro-USB input boards with protection on them, but am unsure if this is the same thing or whether this is simply protecting against surges during charging etc*)
- Step-up module
- 2x 5W speakers
- Capacitor
- Micro-USB charger board

I have attached a screenshot of the video with all parts laid out
[image]

Comment: The blue board that's mounted to a green board can be found here: https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-csr8645-bluetooth-module.html

It's a csr8645 bluetooth audio module.

Comment: The object furthest to the right is the step-up module (boost converter). You can find plenty of chinese-made ones by searching for "boost converter" or "step-up module" or similar on Amazon -- just look for something with matching input and output voltages to what you need, and physically similar in size (which will tend to correlate with current-handling capability, which I assume you don't have specs for.)

Comment: [This is a **written** explanation of how to build one, with parts named and links to sources.](https://www.instructables.com/id/Portable-Bluetooth-Speaker-2x3W-Finished-/)

Comment: The best search terms I can find for the battery charger circuit (again on amazon) are something like "micro usb lithium battery circuit". That turns up dozens of examples (again you will want to match exact voltages and things yourself.)

Comment: @JRE - Did you use a protector circuit for the battery at all?

Comment: That's not my project, but the charging circuit claims some kind of protection function.

Comment: the micro usb charger is the TP4056 1A Lipo Battery Charger Module

Comment: the instructables link uses a usb charger with in-built protection

Comment: @Jasen - Is the circuit protection merely for surges from power input to recharge, or is this also a protection circuit for the battery?

Comment: it's to protect the battery, this is important because damaged lithium batteries start fires.

Comment: @Jasen of course! Don't want my gift to be deadly XD. I was thinking more along the lines of, would the protection circuit in the USB charging board be the same as if I were to buy a battery specific charging board (ie: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/1S-3-7V-2A-BMS-PCM-18650-Lipo-Battery-Protection-Board-PCB-Lithium-li-on-Battery/143080534769?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649)?

Comment: these board work by monitoring the battery voltage, they work for any size of single cell lithium-ion  battery they are not particularly specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of scowering the web, Aliexpress and cross-referencing with Ebay, I found the following items corresponding to the image above:

- [Bluetooth amplifier board BK3260](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Bluetooth-amplifier-board-module-AUX-audio-receiver-BK3260-stereo-V4-2-5W-5w-amp/332647887429?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649)
- [2A Step Up Converter Board](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Boost-Module-2A-Step-Up-Converter-2V-24V-To-5V-9V-12V-28V-Power-Supply-Board/163477927511?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&var=462835879866&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649)
- [Micro USB TP4056 li-ion Charger Module](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Micro-USB-TP4056-li-ion-li-po-lipo-Battery-Charger-Module-Discharge-Protection/272986428636?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&var=572203917031&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649)
- [3 Pin 2 Position Slide Switch 5V 0.3A](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/3-Pcs-3-Pin-2-Position-Mini-Size-SPDT-Slide-Switches-On-Off-PCB-5V-0-3A-Switch/172416803723?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649)
- [3.7V 2A Battery Protection Board](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/1S-3-7V-2A-BMS-PCM-18650-Lipo-Battery-Protection-Board-PCB-Lithium-li-on-Battery/143080534769?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649)

Comment: That TP4056 mudule you found includes over discharge protection (it is the same one in the instrictable) ,you an use the out terminals instead of connecting the amplifiwr and boost converter via the protection board

Comment: @Jasen I'm not sure what you mean. Could you explain again? I'm a n00b at this stuff XD

Comment: see the instructable link from the you-tube video